# aws adfs command mac m2

Tags: macos, zsh, aws-cli

I'm trying to install aws-adfs on my mac M2 following this procedure:

https://pypi.org/project/aws-adfs/

Unfortunately despite the fact that the procedure seems to be successful when I launch a command   "aws-adfs login --adfs-host=my host url --session-duration 14400"
I receive "zsh: command not found: aws-adfs" .
Any suggestions?

Really thanks

Answer (score 0):

You apparently did a user local installation and missed this step:

> Please note, that you need to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your `PATH`

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, where would PATH be and how do I add $HOME/.local/bin ? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Create `~/.zshenv` and put there `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH`, then restart the shell.